# Beam Pipeline with CheckStopReadingFn throws IllegalStateException upon returning true from CheckStopReadingFn

Tags: apache-beam

I am using Apache Beam 2.29.0 to consume from Kafka. I added the function CheckStopReadingFn to stop reading from Kafka once the test returns true. My pipeline creation is like this:

```
        return p.apply("Read from Kafka", KafkaIO.<byte[], GenericRecord>read()
                    .withBootstrapServers(options.getSourceBrokers().get())
                    .withTopics(srcTopics)
                    .withConsumerConfigUpdates(consumerExtraOptions)
                    .withConsumerFactoryFn(new ConsumerFactoryFn(offsetInfo))
                    .withConsumerConfigUpdates(ImmutableMap.of("group.id", "my_group"))
                    .withCheckStopReadingFn(new CheckStopReadingFn(options.getProjectId().get()))
                    .withKeyDeserializer(ByteArrayDeserializer.class)
                    .withStartReadTime(Instant.ofEpochMilli(options.getStartTimestamp().get()))
                    .withValueDeserializer(ConfluentSchemaRegistryDeserializerProvider.of(options.getSourceSchemaRegistryUrl().get(), options.getSourceSubject().get()))
                    .withoutMetadata()).apply("Drop keys", Values.<GenericRecord>create())
            .apply("Windowing of " + windowDuration + " seconds", Window.<GenericRecord>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(windowDuration))));
```

The place in Beam that throws the exception is in the OffsetTracker method below because the lastAttempedOffset is null:

```
    @Override
  public void checkDone() throws IllegalStateException {
    if (range.getFrom() == range.getTo()) {
      return;
    }
    checkState(
        lastAttemptedOffset != null,
        "Last attempted offset should not be null. No work was claimed in non-empty range %s.",
        range);
    checkState(
        lastAttemptedOffset >= range.getTo() - 1,
        "Last attempted offset was %s in range %s, claiming work in [%s, %s) was not attempted",
        lastAttemptedOffset,
        range,
        lastAttemptedOffset + 1,
        range.getTo());
  }
```

Any ideas what the problem might be?

Here is my CheckStopReadingFn implementation:

```
private static class CheckStopReadingFn implements SerializableFunction<TopicPartition, Boolean> {
    final private String projectId;
    final private String bucketName;
    final private String subdirectory;

    CheckStopReadingFn(String projectId, String bucketName, String subdirectory ) {
        this.projectId = projectId;
        this.bucketName = bucketName;
        this.viewName = subdirectory;
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean apply(TopicPartition topicPartition) {
        return = GCSUtility.filesExist(projectId, bucketName, subdirectory, Set.of(topicPartition.toString()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the contents of CheckStopReadingFn? Based on the error message it seems likely that function is triggering immediately and the function stops before reading anything.

Comment: @Fabio, did you find the answer. I am having same issue

Comment: @Nishant that function did not work for me. I end up implementing the functionality is a different way.

Comment: @Fabio, could you elaborate your way if possible. Thanks